# Why ANTLR generated parser has not parse/start/begin functions?

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4

I am trying to generate parser with ANTLR for the minimalistic grammar of First Order Logic, that can be found at the ANTLR source code: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/fol/fol.g4

The strange thing is, that the generated Parser has no `parse`, `begin`, `start` methods that can be seen in every tutorial. Listener is generated as well, but I am interested to get the parse tree (for later manipulation) and, besides, many tutorials that mention listeners, use one of mentioned 3 functions anyway. What has gone wrong? Are there parser generation options?

The mentioned methods are not included in the generated code, yes, they may be in the base class, but Eclipse consider their us as error (undefined methods).

I am using antlr 4.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generated parser class will have methods with the same names as the rules you define in your grammar. So if your grammar has a rule named `foobar` and you want to parse your input according to that rule, you'd call `parser.foobar()` to do so.

If the code in your tutorial calls a method named `parse`, `begin` or `start`, then the grammar in that tutorial almost certainly defines a rule with that name.

In the grammar you linked, the main rule is called `condition`, so that's the method that you should be calling.